# Use KIE 7.73.0.Final with Camel 3.11.7 in Karaf 4.4.0

Tags: apache-camel, drools, apache-karaf, kie

I want to migrate KIE 6.2.0.Final and DROOLS 6.2.0.Final which work fine with Apache Camel 2.25 in Apache Servicemix 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT (Karaf 4.0.7) to

KIE 7.73.0.Final, DROOLS 7.73.0.Final, Apache Camel 3.11.7 in Apache Karaf 4.4.0

I checked all kie-camel.jar Versions, they use and implement intern camel 2.24. But this jar can not work for me, because the KiePolicy class which implements Policy Class in Camel3 has different Methods than Camel2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-camel</artifactId>
    <version>7.73.0.Final </version>
</dependency>
```

Where can I find the kie-camel jar which using camel 3?

Is there any documentation or Examples which explain using Kie, Drools 7.73.0.Final with Camel 3 in Karaf 4.4.0?

Best regards
Amjad

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Drools github repositories and it looks like kie-parent pins Camel 2.24.0 up until now. (All releases, and current 'main' branch.)

As of now, there's no official version of kie-camel with a Camel 3 dependency. You'll need to either fork the repository and fix it yourself, find a third-party library that provides the same functionality, or implement the Camel 3 support yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem we implemented kie-camel to support camel3:

We downloaded the source code for kie-camel/7.72.0.Final then we changed the dependency in pom.xml to use camel 3.11.7
Then we changed the Code in the Java-Code, hier are the changes which we have done:

`import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent;` to `import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent;`

`import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultEndpoint;` to `import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint;`

`import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange;` to `import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange;`

`import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage;` to `import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultMessage;`

`import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducer;` to `import org.apache.camel.support.DefaultProducer;`

`import org.apache.camel.spi.RouteContext;` to `import org.apache.camel.Route;`

`import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConstants;`
to `import org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.message.CxfConstants;`

`executor = component.getCamelContext().getRegistry().lookup(ksessionId, CommandExecutor.class);`
to `executor = component.getCamelContext().getRegistry().lookupByNameAndType(ksessionId, CommandExecutor.class);`

`dformatDefinition = routeContext.getCamelContext().resolveDataFormatDefinition(ref);`
to `dformatDefinition = new DataFormatDefinition(route.getCamelContext().resolveDataFormat(ref));`

`Map<String, String[]> map = xstreamDataFormat.getImplicitCollections();`
to `List<PropertyDefinition> map = xstreamDataFormat.getImplicitCollections();`

`List<String> converters = xstreamDataFormat.getConverters();`
to  `List<PropertyDefinition> converters = xstreamDataFormat.getConverters();`

`List<String> converters = xstreamDataFormat.getConverters();` to `List<PropertyDefinition> converters = xstreamDataFormat.getConverters();`

In KiePolicy.java, method getKieNode:
`if (!nav.getOutputs().isEmpty()) {  List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputs = nav.getOutputs();` to `List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputsProcessorDefinition = null; if (nav instanceof BeanDefinition) { BeanDefinition beanDefinition = (BeanDefinition) nav; outputsProcessorDefinition = beanDefinition.getOutputs(); }else if (nav instanceof PolicyDefinition) { PolicyDefinition policyDefinition = (PolicyDefinition) nav; outputsProcessorDefinition = policyDefinition.getOutputs(); } if (outputsProcessorDefinition!=null && !outputsProcessorDefinition.isEmpty()) { List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputs = outputsProcessorDefinition;`

In KiePolicy.java, method augmentNodes:
`for (ProcessorDefinition<?> child : routeDef.getOutputs()) {`
to `List<ProcessorDefinition<?>> outputsProcessorDefinition = null; if (routeDef instanceof BeanDefinition) { BeanDefinition beanDefinition = (BeanDefinition) routeDef; outputsProcessorDefinition = beanDefinition.getOutputs(); }else if (routeDef instanceof PolicyDefinition) { PolicyDefinition policyDefinition = (PolicyDefinition) routeDef; outputsProcessorDefinition = policyDefinition.getOutputs(); } ToDefinition toDrools = null; if(outputsProcessorDefinition!=null) { for (ProcessorDefinition<?> child : outputsProcessorDefinition)`

Then we built our an new jar and use it.